# process overnight time data dataframe in Julia

Tags: julia

My original data contains hour data for around 1 day. I want to add the overnight data 1 day; how to do it in Julia's way?

```
using CSV, DataFrames, Dates
path = tempname()
write(path, "t\n9\n12\n18\n0\n5\n")
df = CSV.read(path, DataFrame, types=Dict(:t=>DateTime), dateformat="H")
```

df output

```
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ t
     │ DateTime
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0001-01-01T09:00:00
   2 │ 0001-01-01T12:00:00
   3 │ 0001-01-01T18:00:00
   4 │ 0001-01-01T00:00:00   <- add Day(1) expected be 0001-01-02
   5 │ 0001-01-01T05:00:00   <- add Day(1) expected be 0001-01-02
```

Comment: Can you please put the exact expected output? Do you mean that the `0001-01-01T00:00:00` should be `0001-01-02T00:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is

```
julia> write(path, "t\n9\n12\n18\n0\n5\n21\n4")
18

julia> df = CSV.read(path, DataFrame, types=Dict(:t=>DateTime), dateformat="H")
7×1 DataFrame
 Row │ t                   
     │ DateTime            
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0001-01-01T09:00:00
   2 │ 0001-01-01T12:00:00
   3 │ 0001-01-01T18:00:00
   4 │ 0001-01-01T00:00:00
   5 │ 0001-01-01T05:00:00
   6 │ 0001-01-01T21:00:00
   7 │ 0001-01-01T04:00:00
```

(spans three days i.e. one more day than the data in the question)

Every time the hour is lesser than the previous hour value, we'll assume it's the data for a new day. To detect this, we can use `sign.(diff(df.t))`

```
julia> sign.(diff(df.t))
6-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  1
 -1
  1
  1
 -1
```

We can check for the places where these values are less than 0 (i.e. -1). Those signify the date transitions in this data. Appying `cumsum` on that result will give us the date increments to be applied to each row.

```
julia> sign.(diff(df.t)) .< 0
6-element BitVector:
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1

julia> dateincrements = cumsum(sign.(diff(df.t)) .< 0)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 2
```

We can now convert these to the `Day` datatype and add them to the `t` column. (The first row is the basis for the comparison and is assumed to have the date we want to start at, so the addition is done to the rest of the rows.)

```
julia> df.t[2:end] .+= Day.(dateincrements);

julia> df
7×1 DataFrame
 Row │ t                   
     │ DateTime            
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0001-01-01T09:00:00
   2 │ 0001-01-01T12:00:00
   3 │ 0001-01-01T18:00:00
   4 │ 0001-01-02T00:00:00
   5 │ 0001-01-02T05:00:00
   6 │ 0001-01-02T21:00:00
   7 │ 0001-01-03T04:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
replace!(x -> x+Day(1), @view df.t[4:5]);
```

Here is the result

```
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ t
     │ DateTime
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0001-01-01T09:00:00
   2 │ 0001-01-01T12:00:00
   3 │ 0001-01-01T18:00:00
   4 │ 0001-01-02T00:00:00
   5 │ 0001-01-02T05:00:00
```

If you want rather to add a day when the hour is lower than some  threshold than `replace!(x -> hour(x) <= 6 ? x+Day(1) : x, df.t);`

Comment: Seems the module isn't elegant enough to automatically add to the day counter.

Comment: The difficult part is how to find the index '4',  by my data, seems previous value greater than next value, then the next value's index is the switch index.

Comment: `findall(==(1),(@view df.t[2:end]) .< (@view df.t[1:end-1])).+1`